# Express and PM2 on Azure port 80

Tags: node.js, azure, express, pm2

My problem is the following:

I have an Azure VM running Ubuntu 16.04 and I have an Express app

```
http.createServer(app).listen(80, function(){
 console.log('App running on port 80'.);
});
```

I have `ufw` enabled with port 80 allowed and the same in Azure rules.

I have done `sudo setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' /usr/bin/node`

Then I do `pm2 start index.js`.

The app starts fine with no logs but I tried to access it from my local computer and get:

```
curl -I http://parse.sensa-platform.com/public/test.txt
curl: (7) Failed to connect to parse.sensa-platform.com port 80: Connection refused
```

It should output `Banans`.

I can `curl` inside the VM.

Don't know what to do. Please help.

```
netstat -an | grep 80
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.4:45152          168.63.129.16:80        TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.4:45282          168.63.129.16:80        TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.4:45262          168.63.129.16:80        TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.4:45202          168.63.129.16:80        TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.4:44480          13.95.240.73:443        TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.4:45312          168.63.129.16:80        TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.4:45292          168.63.129.16:80        TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.4:45232          168.63.129.16:80        TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.4:45212          168.63.129.16:80        TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.4:45192          168.63.129.16:80        TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.4:45252          168.63.129.16:80        TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.4:45162          168.63.129.16:80        TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.4:45172          168.63.129.16:80        TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.4:45222          168.63.129.16:80        TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.4:45322          168.63.129.16:80        TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.4:45182          168.63.129.16:80        TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.4:45272          168.63.129.16:80        TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.4:45242          168.63.129.16:80        TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.4:45302          168.63.129.16:80        TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.4:45142          168.63.129.16:80        TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 10.0.0.4:44380          13.95.240.73:443        TIME_WAIT  
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

Comment: Did you expose 80/TCP in the Network Security Group (Azure Portal)?

Comment: Hi, yes I did exposed it in the NSG. That is why it is strange.

Comment: nestat - an | grep 80 should help. If you are indeed listening on 0.0.0.0 on 80 then see if iptables filters anything on the  INPUT chain. You should be running pm2 with sudo to listen to ports <1024.

Comment: Do I still need sudo even when using `sudo setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' /usr/bin/node`? Also added the output of netstat

Comment: I have no idea what setcap does but if netstat shows a binding on 0.0.0.0:80 then you're all good on that part.

Comment: All this hoping that your domain points to the right thing, double check that too.

Comment: Yes I have an A record pointing to the correct IP address.

Comment: If you test `curl -I http://<public IP>/public/test.txt`, what is the result?

Comment: I get curl: (52) Empty reply from server